# Respecting condition after INSERT C# and T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm inserting a new team in a championship in a table but a championship can't exceed more than X teams. How do it work with conditions?

Example, in my C# code I have this:

```
if (listBox_AffiliatedTeams.Items.Count > Convert.ToInt32(label_nbrTeams.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Sorry, the maximum of different teams is already reached !");
}
else
    try
    {
        if(PlayerSelected == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select first a player to join");
        }
        else
        aService.NewAffiliation(championshipSelected.Ch_Year, 1, PlayerSelected.Pl_LastName, PlayerSelected.Pl_FirstName, TeamSelected.Te_Name);
```

When the championship reaches the maximum of teams (4 for example), if I add a new team it works. Only after the 5 team added, the condition is respected but I still have one more team than the maximum.
And I want to avoid to exceed this maximum.

EDIT: In reality, I insert players affiliated to a team for a championship, so I need to be able to insert more than one the same team.

Only when the team inserted is different than the others team, the number of teams increase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a way. Not pretty but it works :P
I use a list of string with all the team's name, then use a ".contains".

```
List<Affiliation_GetTeamsNameAffilied_Result> list = (List<Affiliation_GetTeamsNameAffilied_Result>)listBox_AffiliatedTeams.DataSource;
            List<string> lstTeam = new List<string>();

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                lstTeam.Add(item.Te_Name.ToString());
            }
            if (listBox_AffiliatedTeams.Items.Count > Convert.ToInt32(label_nbrTeams.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, the maximum of different teams is already reached !");
            }
            else
                try
                {
                    if(PlayerSelected == null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please select first a player to join");
                    }
                    else
                        if (lstTeam.Contains(TeamSelected.Te_Name.ToString()))
                    aService.NewAffiliation(championshipSelected.Ch_Year, 1, PlayerSelected.Pl_LastName, PlayerSelected.Pl_FirstName, TeamSelected.Te_Name);
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, the maximum of different teams is already reached !");
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should replace your `>` in your if statement with a `>=`. If the count is 4 and the maximum is 4, 4 is not greater than 4 so team will still be inserted. If you use a `>=` you should avoid this issue, since 4 is less than or equal to 4 and the team will not be inserted.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention that I actually need to insert more than  once the same team (in reality, I insert players affiliated to a team for a championship)

I'm gonna Edit.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed your comment. I'm glad you figured it out, though!